# What does the phrase "tell us what you really think" mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

What does "tell us what you really think" mean? It seems to be used when someone *is* telling us what they really think...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The phrase is often used ironically as a reaction to a strongly-expressed opinion.

A non-ironic use, to draw out a stronger opinion:

> "So, what do you think of the website's new layout?"
>
> "Oh, it's okay..."
>
> "Come on, even I know there are a few mistakes in there; tell us what you really think."

An ironic use, as a reaction to a strong opinion:

> "I hate him, I never want to see him again, and I hope he catches a terrible disease!"
>
> "But tell us what you *really* think about him, Sally."

Answer (score 3):

It might be used when it is apparent that speakers are not expressing their true feelings. *Tell us what you really think* is an encouragment to them be honest about them.

Comment: But today in the US it is often employed sarcastically when someone expresses an opinion more forcibly than is normal in the context.

Comment: Being across the other side of the Atlantic, I didn't know that. But there must be many expressions that can be used sarcastically in this way.

Comment: Oh, yes--practically anything. That one's just become commonplace in the last ten years or so.